# Making a selfrole button bot in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord.py bot, it could let you grab roles clicking on buttons.
But I'm struggling , i don't even really know what part exactly is not working.
my idea is to :

- Check when a button is clicked (I'm 70% sure that i don't have to do anything for this but i'm struggling to find information online soo)
- When a button is clicked, check the roles the user has
- If, he already has the role, take it back, if not :
- Give him the role

But i can't fin documentation (good enough) online.

my code for now is this :

```py
import discord
from discord import *

client = discord.Bot()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("connected")

class Selfroles(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
    
    @discord.ui.button(label="Red", style = discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id = "red")
    async def red_role(self, ctx, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Red")
        user = ctx.author
        if role in ctx.author.roles: 
            await interaction.user.remove_roles(1144440508383494204)
        else: 
            await interaction.user.add_roles(1144440508383494204)
        

@client.command()
async def selfrole(ctx):
    await ctx.send(view=Selfroles())

client.run(token)
```

and my bot commands aren't even appearing on discord now lmao. thx for the help :)

### SOLUTION : (by user:sicco14)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import Select, View, Button

APP_ID = 12345678910111213
TOKEN = 'ENTER_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE'

class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all(), application_id=APP_ID)
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("BOT is Ready")

bot = MyBot()

class Selfroles(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, ctx) -> None:
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.ctx = ctx
    
    @discord.ui.button(label="Red", style = discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def red_role(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        red_role = discord.utils.get(self.ctx.guild.roles, name="Red")
        if red_role in self.ctx.author.roles: 
            await interaction.user.remove_roles(red_role)
        else: 
            await interaction.user.add_roles(red_role)

@bot.command()
async def selfrole(ctx):
    await ctx.send(view=Selfroles(ctx))

bot.run(TOKEN, reconnect=True)
```

I had to change the order of `button: discord.ui.Button` and `interaction: discord.Interaction` from the og solution because (i'm not sure) i'm using discord.py

Comment: This question is very broad as you didn't pin down the problem and you let us do that. To start with commands take a look at the [official discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html). Reading documentation is always good when you get stuck

Comment: @ShadowCrafter_01 I would, but the documentation never approach this problem, or at least i couldn't find it. And i don't ask for someone to code it for me, that would be lazy, only if someone could tell me what i i did wrong or if i mistaken in my syntaxe. thx anyway !!

Comment: Well you mentioned you had trouble with the commands not showing up. The documentation section I sent in my first commend addresses commands. Take a look at that to get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what youre looking for, at least this is working for me. Make sure to insert your TOKEN and your APP_ID (rightclick on your bot -> copy user ID). In my example you trigger the command with **!selfrole**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import Select, View, Button

APP_ID = 12345678910111213
TOKEN = 'ENTER_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE'

class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all(), application_id=APP_ID)
    async def on_ready(self):
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name='!selfrole'))
        print("BOT is Ready")

bot = MyBot()

class Selfroles(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, ctx) -> None:
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.ctx = ctx
    
    @discord.ui.button(label="Red", style = discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def red_role(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        red_role = discord.utils.get(self.ctx.guild.roles, name="Red")
        if red_role in self.ctx.author.roles: 
            await interaction.user.remove_roles(red_role)
            await interaction.response.send_message("red_role removed", ephemeral=True)
        else: 
            await interaction.user.add_roles(red_role)
            await interaction.response.send_message("red_role added", ephemeral=True)

@bot.command()
async def selfrole(ctx):
    await ctx.send(view=Selfroles(ctx))

bot.run(TOKEN, reconnect=True)
```

Comment: That doesn't answer OP's question. **!** and other prefix commands are outdated as Discord recommends using **/**. There's also a feature that lets you add a button to trigger a bot command to your message which is what OP was looking for.

Comment: and why do you think it does not answer his question? The code das exactly what he wants. Also he wanted a prefix command, so I didnt change that

Comment: I don't think OP mentioned anywhere that he wanted a prefixed command. I rather think becuase he said "and my bot commands aren't even appearing on discord", which most likely means they mean slash commands

Comment: Thx !! it didn't work at first but i fixed the error, it was caused by "button: discord.ui.Button" that was place before "interaction: discord..." i think that this is because you're using pycord and me discord.py. made a few changes and it's perfect, tysm!

Comment: No I am also using discord.py .. but I'm glad it works now!